# Mapping one data set parameter with one of the fields returned by another data set in ireport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am developing reports in web application  using **ireport designer4.0.2**.In my report I have a table having cell containing another table.The query of data set of 2nd table depends on one of the fields returned from 1st table.ie I have to map one of the fields of 1st data set with parameter of 2nd data set.How it will accomplish.Please advice me as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

> **"The query of data set of 2nd table depends on one of the fields
>   returned from 1st table"**

If you are looking to return values from a `table` data set.  **It is not possible.**

A `table` data set  does not return values to the main reports like the `sub reports` do.

You can opt for `sub-reports` if you need to return values back.